# Order of names in title

Tags: technical-writing, business-writing

I and two other students are writing a proposal to a corporation to donate some equipment to the Electrical Engineering department at my school. When I put our names under the title of the proposal, is there a particular order they should go in, e.g alphabetical or seniority-based?

Comment: As there are different rules in different fields you must ask your professors.

Answer (score 3):

If one of you is obviously senior to the other in some relevant way, then put that person’s name first. If you are both reasonably similar in standing, then put your names in alphabetical order.